# What is the corret syntax for using max function

Tags: reporting, odoo

Still using bloody OpenOffice Writer to customize my sale_order.rml report.

In my sale order I have 6 order lines with 6 different lead time to delivery. I need to show the maximum out of the six values.

After many attempt I have abandoned using the reduce function as it works erratically or not at all most of the time. I have never seen anything like this.

So I thought I'd give a try using max encapsulating a loop such as:

```
[[ max(repeatIn(so.order_line.delay,'d')) ]]
```

My maximum lead time being 20, I would expect to see 20 (yes well that would be too easy, wouldn't it!).

It returns

```
{'d': 20.0}
```

At least it contains the value I am after.
But; if I try and manipulate this result, it disappears altogether.
I have tried:

```
int(re.findall(r'[0-9]+', max(repeatIn(so.order_line.delay,'d')))[0])
```

which works great from the python window, but returns absolutely nothing in OpenERP.

I import the re from my sale_order.py file, which I have recompiled into sale_order.pyo:

```
    import time
    import re
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from report import report_sxw

    class order(report_sxw.rml_parse):
        def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
            super(order, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
            self.localcontext.update({
                'time': time,
                'datetime': datetime,
                'timedelta': timedelta,
                're': re,
            })
```

I have of course restarted the server many times. My test install sits on windows.

So can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, because I can make it work from Python but not from OpenOffice Writer!

Thanks for your help!

EDIT 1:

The format

```
    {'d': 20.0}
```

is, according to python, a dictionary. Still in Python, to extract the integer from a dictionary it is possible to do it like so:

```
    >>> dict={'d': 20.0}
    >>> print(dict['d'])
    20.0
```

But how can I transpose this to OpenERP writer???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to get the result I wanted by importing functools and declaring the reduce function within the parameters of the sale_order.py file.

I then simply used a combination of reduce and max function and it works exactly as expected.

The correct syntax is as follow:

```
    repeatIn(objects,'o')
    reduce(lambda x, y: max(x, y.delay), o.order_line, 0)
```

Nothing else is required.

Enjoy!